# How can I load two different set of datas to a dynamic dependent drop down?

Tags: mysql, ajax, codeigniter, model-view-controller, codeigniter-3

Actually I am using two dropdowns where first dropdown selects 'Department' and once the department is loaded in the first dropdown, employees in the relevant department loads in the second.
It works fine. But what i need now is I need to load employees of the currently logged in users department and Other department heads in the second dropdown. How can I query this in CodeIgniter Model. This is my table in database

**This is my Table:-**
[image]

**My table to query:-**

Here when I select 'Admin" [Say Admin Head is logged in] Department I need to

select all 'user_level = 2' and 'user_dept = Admin' and with this I need to include all other 'user_level = 3'

Like wise i need to show logged in users department employees and other departments heads only in second dropdown.

My AJAX from View through controller successfully returns the query that i wrote in model.

But i need help to query the specific thing that I needed in CodeIgniter query.

This is my Model funtion which only returns user_level = 3

```
function fetch_dept_officers_for_forward($Dept)  //for forward by dHead
    {
        //echo "Test";
        echo $this->session->userdata('udept');
        $this->db->where('user_dept',$Dept);
        //$this->db->where('user_level','3');
        $this->db->or_where('user_level','3');
        $this->db->order_by('user_name', 'ASC');
        $query = $this->db->get('tbl_users');

        $output = '<option value="">Select Officer</option>';
          foreach($query->result() as $row)
          {
    
            $output .= '<option value="'.$row->user_name.'">'.$row->user_name.'</option>';

          }
          return $output;
    }
```

Comment: anybody out there to help?

Comment: what problem you actually get?

Comment: I need a query for my crieteria